# Web service Port number gets added automatically

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, iis

I created and deployed a webservice in IIS. I was accessing the same using

```
http://abc.net:1111/getmethod
```

Later i gave the URL a synonym so that I could access it without port number as follows

```
http://xyz.net/getmethod
```

If i hit on the above URL i am able to see the "getmethod".

But the problem here is when I mouseover/hit on the invoke button I see the URL changes to

```
http://abc.net:1111/getmethod
```

Port number is getting appended to it automatically.

OS: Windows 2003, IIS: 6.0

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Probably, you need to set AllowMultipleSiteBinding to true

Comment: Where do i see this property?

Comment: Sorry, it's multipleSiteBindingsEnabled: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358763(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am sorry that i am using .net framework 3.5. Unfortunately this property is not available in this version.